# Unable to associate company's Wi-Fi certificate with our Wi-Fi network

Tags: wi-fi, certificates

I have a tablet running Android 4.0.3 that I'm trying to connect to my company's Wi-Fi that uses a security certificate.  I've obtained the certificate and successfully installed it on my tablet but when I go to the Wi-Fi settings to connect to the cooresponding Wi-Fi network, there is no where for me to specify to use the certificate for authentication.  Is this an issue w/ this version of Android, am I doing something wrong, or is there something wrong at the cert level.  We use the same cert on iPhones/iPads (converted for ios use) and the cert specifies which Wi-Fi network to connect to so I assume that is what's supposed to happen on my tablet.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't check on ICS right now but on 2.x the popup when you click to connect to a new network has dropdowns for both CA and user certificates.  You should try adding the network rather than relying on the cert to specify it, at least.

Comment: unfortunately when I go to manually add the network there is still no option for choosing certificates but I think I see the problem.  The network is showing as secured using WEP.  Another nearby network shows as secured with 802.1x and when I attempt to connect to that one I get the dropdowns for adding a certificate.  Sounds like it's the way our wifi network was set up and secured that's the issue.

Comment: so further testing and info from the admin who configured our company's wifi is that I should manually set it up as an 802.1x PEAP type network using PAP as the phase 2 security.  I can then add the cert but once I save the network it shows as out of range.

Answer (score 1):

The option to choose a certificate is available with enterprise encryption (802.1x).

Judging by your comment, your android thinks it is using a different encryption method than it should, so have you attempted manually adding the network, and specifying the encryption type?

Please bear in mind that *not all* wifi cards and devices support that encryption method.

Answer (score -1):

Try [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid) from the Play Store. It might solve your problem.

Comment: Could you please give some more details on *how* the mentioned app is supposed to solve the issue? Thanks!